# Pubnub ChatEngine Error

Tags: pubnub

I get this error when I try to use ChatEngine
[image]

The code is :

`

```
let ChatEngine = ChatEngineCore.create({
    publishKey: 'pub-c-bcc15813-f77d-4c89-a56a-18ac89bc8ad5',
    subscribeKey: 'sub-c-8a4f7218-67db-11e8-9683-aecdde7ceb31'
});

// Provide a unique id and other profile information for your user here.
const uuid = String(new Date().getTime());
ChatEngine.connect(uuid, {
    nickName: "YourUsersNickNameHere",
    favoriteColor: "Red"
});
ChatEngine.on('$.ready', function(data) {
    console.log('ChatEngine ready to go!');
});
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChatEngine requires a specific **PubNub Function** to be running on the key set in which you are connecting.

A 404 is usually caused by that Function being disabled, deleted, missing, etc. In order to enable this PubNub Function, you must run the [ChatEngine Setup](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat-engine/getting-started?devrel_so=adamb#automagic-pubnub-setup).

If you haven't already, it will ask you to log in to your free PubNub account. Click the **Setup** [button](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat-engine/getting-started?devrel_so=adamb#automagic-pubnub-setup).
[image: ChatEngine Setup Button]

Clicking this button will create a new key set in your account, and deploy the PubNub Function on that key set.

**If you do not want to change key sets**, you can copy and paste the Functions code from the newly made ChatEngine App to your old keyset. You can delete the new key set if you don't want to use it.

When creating the PubNub Functions event handler in your old app, make sure that you select **On Request** as the event handler type, and configure the **path** to `chat-engine-server`. Lastly click the play button on the right.

This should give your front end a resource to access on the back end, and there will be no more 404 error.